# Upload file using Jquery form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I am using [Jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) to upload file in Ajax request.File is successfully sent to server but on response browser is asking to save response with following popup

[image]

Here is my HTML

```
<form:form name="newRequestForm" id="newRequestForm" modelAttribute="requestForm" method="POST">     
<form:input path="mrnFile" type="file" size="40"/>
</form:form>
```

JS

```
    // Initializing Jquery form 
     $(function() {
        $('#newRequestForm').ajaxForm();   
    });

   // This function is called on click event of submit button  
function submitDataRequest(formAction) {
    var options = { 
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
                success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
                url:  formAction,
                dataType:  'json'
            }; 
     $('#newRequestForm').ajaxSubmit(options); 
}   


function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    alert('About to submit: '); 
    return true; 
} 

function showResponse(data, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    Alert("In response..")
    if (!data.actionPassed) {
        showErrors(data.errors);
        $("#hideOrShowErrors").show();  
    } else {
        showConfirmation(data, confirmationMsg, formName, successFormAction);
    }
}
```

`showResponse` is never invoked instead browser shows the popup.
I checked through Firebug, the response code is `200` still success callback is not executed.
 After reading some similar question I think it has something to do with server response type. So I did following in my spring controller

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> save(@ModelAttribute("dataRequestForm") DataRequestFormDTO dataRequestFormDTO, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {  
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO>(responseDTO, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

On both side I have data type as `json` but still I am getting the popup.Am I making any blunder?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Updated JS

```
function submitDataRequest(formAction) {
     var options = { 

                  beforeSubmit: function(){ 
                  alert("Before submit");
                  },  // pre-submit callback 
                    success: function(){
                    alert("On success");
                    },  // post-submit callback 
                    url:  formAction
    }  
         $('#newRequestForm').ajaxSubmit(options); 
 }
```

Still I get the same popup and `success` callback is not fired.

Added `initBinder` in controller

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request,
            ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws ServletException {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(CommonsMultipartFile.class,
                new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());    
    }
```

After adding `initBinder` I got following error

```
No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with IE and iframe (used  by jquery form plugin to upload files with ajax).

I solved in two steps:

1) Server Side: **remove headers**, send back just the content.

2) Client-Side: do not set the ajax request **dataType** parameter and on success use the following code to extract json:

```
success: function(data)
{
    try{
        jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        // continue process with json encoded data
    }
    catch(e)  
    {
        // handle parsing error
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am facing same issue in Firefox also.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still facing same issue. I also tried adding `initBinder` in my controller but no luck.

Comment: @FabrizioD'Ammassa. Hi Fabrizio, I am facing a problem that's very similar and I've posted iton this page with a bounty on it. I've not been able to solve it yet. Can you please take a look and see if you can solve this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729645/jquery-file-upload-using-post-redirects-to-post-response - Thanks.