# File upload over Ajax in Spring 3.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, file, file-upload

Which is the best or easiest ways to upload file over Ajax in Spring 3.0?
I want to submit a form over Ajax which will contain a File.Also solution should not be dependant on Flash etc. like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  I tried [Jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) but not able to make it work.You can check my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982265/upload-file-using-jquery-form-plugin) for more details.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT :** I want to submit form over Ajax which will contain a file. On server side I want to collect it in a model attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [Ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) it worked. But it calls the controller as soon as file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this using Dojo Iframes. Here's the code for that (need to call it from action="return submitForm();" from the form tag):

```
submitForm = function() {
dojo.io.iframe.send({
    url : "/uploadForm",
    form : "html_form_id",
    method : "POST",
    handleAs : 'text',
    load : function(response, ioArgs) {
            //handle your response here...
            return response;
    },
    error : function(response, ioArgs) {
        if (ioArgs.xhr.status != 0) {
            try {
                //handle error here
            } catch (e5) {
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
});
return false;
}
```

On the server side, in your Spring Controller, you would handle this as:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uploadForm")
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
        final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception 
    { 

        String fileName="";
        if(multipartFile!=null)
        {
                    fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        }

        //file inputstream can be accessed as multipartFile.getInputStream()

        String resultCode = "0";

        final String responseHTML = "<html><head></head><body><textarea>" + resultCode + "</textarea></body></html>";
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        final OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
        responseStream.write(responseHTML.getBytes());
        responseStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        responseStream.close();
    }
```

You'll need to name your file type input parameter as "file" (as the handling functions says @RequestParam("file"))

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.I want to submit a form which have a field of type file. So I want to collect file inside a model attribute.

Comment: Yes. When you create the <form> and name the input type="file" as file, this should work.

Comment: @rogermenezes could you Please post full working sample with jsp,

Answer (score 0):

have you tried malsup jquery form plugin.... it worked fine for me

```
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it. Please go through my question I have added a link regarding it.